# Can we create/store WebGL VBOs on a Java Server?

Tags: javascript, java, graphics, 3d, webgl

One of the problems I'm facing in the 3d graphics application I'm working on (Client written in Javascript & WebGL 1.*, Server that sends geometry data for each object through web socket written in Java) is the initial model loading efficiency. It is because if the set of geometry objects are too big, we first have to serialize that data from the server, deserialize that on the client, and then process it to create different VBOs for each of them finding suitable space in the client memory pool (to eventually send the graphics data to the GPU). My question is, is there a way I can create VBOs on the server itself and transmit them in their 'raw' binary form so that I can just bind them to the GPU buffer data and be done without doing all of it? If I can't create, can I do something like when I create WebGL Buffers on the client side for the first time I send them back and store them on the server for future use?

It will take additional processing on the server to create such buffers but overall it might be time saving if I don't need to serialize/deserialize and then create webgl buffers every time on the client side.

Thanks!